# Combining 2-d arrays to form a 3-d array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm defining a function which will return a 3-d grid. During it, I use a function defined already that returns a 2-d array. I want to join these 2-d arrarys to form the 3-d during an iteration but I've looked at functions like meshgrid(), dstack(), concatenate() but can't seem to get any of them to fit right into the code.

The program models the spread of waves from a point source on the 2-d array, and the 3-d array shows how the displacement of the medium changes over the course of a wavelength.

```
def make_wave_snapshot(size,wavelength,phase):
    waves_array = np.zeros((size,size),np.float)
    if size%2==0:
        for y in range(size):
            for x in range(size):
                r = math.hypot((size/2 - x - 0.5),(size/2 - y - 0.5))
                d = np.sin((2*math.pi*r/wavelength)-phase)/np.sqrt(r)
                waves_array[y,x] = d
        dp.display_2d_array(waves_array) #This is in another module altogether
        return waves_array #Displays array showing values
    else:
        return 'Please use integer of size.'

def make_wave_sequence(size,wavelength,nsteps):
    waves_sequence = np.zeros((nsteps,size,size),np.float)
        if nsteps%1==0:
            for z in range(nsteps):
                make_wave_snapshot(size,wavelength,(2*math.pi*z/nsteps))
                waves_sequence = ???
            return waves_sequence #Displays array showing values
        else:
            return 'Please use positive integer for number of steps'
```

The issue is turning the 'wave_array's into a 'wave_sequence'. Generous commenting would be very appreciated if you write any code. Many thanks!

Comment: I think I see what you're driving at... if my answer (below) is not what you were thinking, could you please give an example your desired `waves_sequence` before and after the `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have a three dimensional array, something like:

```
wave = np.zeros((2, 2, 2), np.float)

([[[0., 0.],
   [0., 0.]],
  [[0., 0.],
   [0., 0.]]])
```

And you want to insert a two dimensional array, returned from your function like:

```
([[ 1., 2.],
  [ 3., 4.]])
```

Such that your 3D array is now:

```
([[[1., 2.],
   [3., 4.]],
  [[0., 0.],
   [0., 0.]]])
```

After the first iteration of your `for` loop. If that is correct, then it's actually pretty simple and you're most of the way there. You can assign an "element" to your 3D array that is a 2D array as long as you select the correct entry:

```
for z in range(nsteps):
    waves_sequence[z] = make_wave_snapshot(size,wavelength,(2*math.pi*z/nsteps))
```